# Can I see a List's history in Trello?

Tags: trello

If a list was created with a certain name, and then renamed - is this history stored/accessible/searchable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List rename actions are not currently displayed or searchable. List creation actions should show up in the board activity feed (clicking 'View all' in the sidebar), though the activity feed is not searchable so it may require clicking through a lot.

Comment: I work on the Trello team. We've heard some confusion about card and list renames actions not being displayed. We may bring them back.

Comment: Thanks. Are they stored internally, and might be made searchable in the future? (Is there such a feature request?)

Comment: Yes, they are stored internally. We haven't heard that feature request, though.

Comment: Don't think they're searchable even today, but it would be nice if they were.